# Default Object accessor (Object = a instead of Object.value = a), Limiting a String internally

Tags: c#, string, operator-overloading, extension-methods

I am trying to create a String object that can be used in place of the standard String object. As I will be using this "LimitedString" alot, My plan was to create an Object that holds an Int/MaxLength and a String/Value.

As it will be used alot and the only thing that matters after the object has been created is the Value (It handles the Length internally), I want to be able to set its "value" using 
InitializedObject = String() instead of InitializedObject.Value = String()

Everything I have tried so far has given me errors. Is this something I cannot do in C#?

Here's the Code for the object:

```
public class LimitedString{
    private int _maxlength;
    private string _value;
    public LimitedString(int length, string text = "")
    {
        _maxlength = length;
        _value = text;
    }
    private string Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set { _value = _value.Truncate(_maxlength); }
    }
    //Operators
    public static implicit operator string(LimitedString ls)
    {
        return ((ls == null) ? null : ls.Value);
    }
    public static implicit operator LimitedString(string text)
    {
        //Needs to return the LimitedString Object That is being manipulated
        return text == null ? null : new LimitedString(text.Length, text);
    }}
```

I am also using this String Extension

```
     public static string Truncate(this string value, int maxLength)
     {
         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)) return value;
         return value.Length <= maxLength ? value : value.Substring(0, maxLength);
     }
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, Please keep in mind that after the object is initialized It must retain its Max Length, and the string (value) needs to be accessible with just the Object.
I believe that string = Object, is working however I cannot make it work the other way around.

Comment: *“Is this something I cannot do in C#?”* Correct.

Comment: `set { _value = _value.Truncate(_maxlength); }` That is going to act "oddly" if you pass `null` as a value.

Comment: `public static implicit operator LimitedString(string text)`
I need it to use the original LimitedString Object instead of making a new one.

Comment: `LimitedString hello = "ahb";` compiles just fine. What is the issue?

Comment: LimitedString hello = new LimitedString(5);
hello = "Hello World";

Hello object should be "Hello" but its "Hello World"

Comment: @Ry- do you know any Method to do this? Create the object in c/c++ and export it as a dll?

Comment: @JasonBrown: No, you just shouldn’t do this. Continue being explicit by setting `.Value` etc.

Comment: @Ry- Aside from the obvious issues about the code becoming unclear, is there any particular reason why this should be avoided. Should I do this with  Byte arrays instead? for the purpose of being absolutely sure that certain strings Cannot have more then x Characters in them.

Comment: `is there any particular reason why this should be avoided.` Because it completely confuses the entire point of assignment. `LimitedString hello = "ahb"; hello = "bobby";` For the first assignment, an object is created and assigned to `hello` as expected. For the second - you expect it to **alter** `hello` instead - which is completely contrary to anyone's expectations of what `=` does. _The fact it doesn't work is also an issue. ;)_